# Array of string not working

Tags: c#

I use a simple array: contentHouseOne[] that contains strings. But in the Do/While loop it isn't working! It seems like the code don't understand that it's a string when a new object is to be created!? It works when I hardcode the string like I show below. Help is preciated! Thanks!

This isn't working:

```
listHouseParts.Add(new HousePart(content, contentHouseOne[i], newPosition));
```

But this works:

```
 listHouseParts.Add(new HousePart(content, "100x100", newPosition));
```

EDIT:

Here are some code to declare arrays

```
string[] contentHouseOne = new string[] { "ruta100x100Red", 
                                          "ruta100x100Grey", 
                                          "ruta100x100Green", 
                                          "ruta100x100Yellow", 
                                          "ruta100x100Blue" };

bool[,] occupiedPositions = new bool[500,500];
```

Here are some code to set all grid positions to false

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridCol; i++)
    for (int ii = 0; ii < gridRow; ii++)
        occupiedPositions[i, ii] = false;
```

And finally here are the code that I have the problem

```
int i = 0;
do
{
    Vector2 newPosition = NewRandomPosition;
    if (occupiedPositions[(int)newPosition.X, (int)newPosition.Y] == false)
    {
        listHouseParts.Add(new HousePart(content, 
                                         contentHouseOne[i], newPosition));
        occupiedPositions[(int)newPosition.X, (int)newPosition.Y] = true;
        i++;
    }
}
while (i <= 5);
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. You haven't given *nearly* enough information about what's going wrong.

Comment: What does `contentHouseOne[]` contain and what does `listHouseParts` do with `HousePart`?

Comment: the way i am understanding,you are using listbox ok then you have to cast array to listbox

Comment: What happens? Do you get an exception when it runs, or is there a compilation error?

Comment: how did you declared "listHouseParts"?

Comment: I get a index out of range exeption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string array includes five elements:

```
string[] contentHouseOne = new string[] { "ruta100x100Red",
                                          "ruta100x100Grey", 
                                          "ruta100x100Green", 
                                          "ruta100x100Yellow", 
                                          "ruta100x100Blue" };
```

But your `while` loop ends if your running variable `i` is greater than 5

```
while (i <= 5);
```

which causes a IndexOutOfBounds exception on `contentHouseOne`, because the 6th element at index 5 isn't defined.
You should change your while condition to `(i < 5)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! (i <= 5) was the problem, now it's working. But your suggestion to use a loop, would that really work!? What if a position in the occupiedPosition is true, then there will be no new object added to the listHouseParts!? Thats why I used Do/While. But If you have a better solution your welcome with a new suggestion

Comment: Nice catch. P.s., @3D-kreativ: If this is the error you get, it would have been even easier to explain if you had included it. Please provide any such info along with your code next time.

Comment: @3D-kreativ no of course, you're right,  while loop is just fine. Monday morning, bad time for creative thinking :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this so atleast you know if its empty or not

```
    HousePart housePart = new HousePart();
    housePart.Content = content;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentHouseOne[i]))
        housePart.ContentHouseOne = contentHouseOne[i];
    else
        housePart.ContentHouseOne = string.Empty;

    housePart.NewPosition = newPosition;

    listHouseParts.Add(housePart);
```

Comment: What happens when you step through with the debugger, and do you check all your variables, be a little more defensive